Is there a way to minify/combine css/js sphinx-extension-assets from the _static directory to have fewer and smaller requests?
When building (readthe)docs with a sphinx-theme, most of the used extensions bring their own css and js files which are being loaded separately (e.g. copybutton.css/js, tabs.css/js, togglebutton.css/js, pygments.css,...) which creates a lot of requests which are mostly un-minified. Is there a native way to bundle those together to have fewer and smaller http requests to speed things up? Couldn't find anything regarding that. As an example straight from the source:
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/ has ~33 requests for css and js files.
Any pointers on how to automatically or manually achieve that would be much appreciated!
Tried looking for extensions or parameters to find a way, no dice.
